# How to join multiple model on a foreign key field using django ORM?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Want to join three tables and get data. Where model_c and model_b have a foreign key to model_a. But all model does not have a foreign key

```py
class Model_A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Model_B(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(Model_A)

    name = models.CharField()

class Model_C(models.Model):
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(Model_A)

    name = models.CharField()
```

Want query as below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM model_c JOIN model_a 
    ON model_a.id = model_c.model_a
    JOIN model_b ON model_a
    ON model_a.id = model_b.model_a;
```

Tried to create a query using **select_related** But did not work.

```py
query = Model_C.objects.select_related('model_a', 'model_a__model_b_set')
```

Error

```
FieldError 
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'model_b_set'. Choices are: x, y
```

Tried to create a query using **prefetch_related** But did not work.

```py
query = Model_C.objects.select_related('model_a', 'model_a__model_b_set')
sql = Model_C.objects.select_related().prefetch_related('model_b').query
```

but above query does not join.

Comment: Add related_name (or use default one) for your ForeignKeys. `Model_c.objects.all().select_related('model_a', 'model_a__model_b_set')`

Comment: Depending on the cardinality of your models you may want to use either select_related or prefetch_related (or not use those at all).

Comment: @gpichot Could you please give an example of  not use select_related or prefetch_related? Because above ex did not return query what I was expecting

Comment: what query did you test so far? And what were the results?

Comment: @gpichot When I print that query it reruns `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: '_model_b'. Choices are: x, y`